# intermediate action button necessary to update graph-not responding

Tags: shiny

The shiny help forum could not seem to help me with this problem...

I have a command from a particular package that outputs a graph. The command requires preliminary processed input via a different command that is defined in the same package. Hence my plan is to create an app whereby the user can interactively update the map. This as far as I can see will require 2 action buttons: "actionbutton A" will re-run the preliminary processing command with input from a "checkboxGroupInput". "actionbutton B" will then update the graph with the new input from the preliminary processing command.

```
#ui.R      
checkboxGroupInput("column_choices", "column choice", colnames(data), selected=c("column1", "column2"....)),
actionButton(inputId="choices", label="Update tag")) 

actionButton(inputId="replot", label="Update plot")),
plotOutput("graph")

#server.R
servercell <- function(input, output) {
  dataInput<-observeEvent(input$choices, {
    isolate(tagData(IRIS[, input$column_choices]))
})
output$SPV<-renderPlot({
  input$replot
  isolate(package_defined_plot_function(data=data, dataTag=dataInput()))
  })
}
```

The buttons work when tested independent of each other: the checkbox input seems to update fine, after clicking "Update tag"/actionbutton A and the graph seems to work fine after clicking "Update plot"/actionbutton B (when dataInput() is not an argument in the plot function).

My problem is that *dataInput<-observeEvent(input$choices, {.....* does not allow the graph to display. When *dataInput()* is made an argument of the plotting function- instead of the graph displaying on the app page- in place of that I get the error: could not find dataInput function

As I said buttons A and B work fine when independent of each other..... however their coexistence conflicts... and having two action buttons is the only way I can think of to update the graph interactively... if anyone can think of how to do it with one button that would be great.

I am stuck ... any tips?

Comment: I think you want `eventReactive` instead of `observeEvent`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to implement a two-step update process. Actually, you could also have the graph redraw immediately once some checkboxes change, unless it is your intention to make updates only on demand, e.g. because of lengthy computations.

In order to implement the update button don't use calls to `isolate` and `observeEvent`; rather use `eventReactive` to create an reactive expression triggered by the button click. You can then use it in your plotting function similarly as you tried before:

**ui.R**

```
checkboxGroupInput("column_choices", "column choice", colnames(data), selected=c("column1", "column2"....)),
actionButton(inputId="button", label="Update plot"),
plotOutput("graph")
```

**server.R**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  dataInput <- eventReactive(input$button, {
    tagData(IRIS[, input$column_choices])
  })
  output$graph <- renderPlot({
    package_defined_plot_function(data=data, dataTag=dataInput()))
    })
})
```

See also *Pattern 2 - Delay reactions* in the [RStudio article](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/action-buttons.html).